# In a hand of bridge what is the probability that you have 5 spades and your partner has remaining 8.

Tags: probability

I am a complete noob in playing cards. Please help me out in this problem and also explain me the concept behind the bridge card game.

Comment: All you need to know is that there are $52$ cards, $13$ of which are spades; you have $13$ of the cards and your partner has another $13$.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to write the answer.

Answer (score 2):

So you should be having $13$ cards out of which $5$ are spades and your partner also has $13$ cards out of which $8$ are spades.

So total number of favourable outcomes (which can be obtained by *picking the spades used for my hand then picking the remaining cards for my hand and at last picking the non-spades for my partner's hand*)

$m=\binom{13}{5}\times\binom{39}{8}\times\binom{31}{5}$

The total number of possible outcomes $n=\binom{52}{13}\times\binom{39}{13}$

Required probability $=\frac{m}{n}\approx2.608399419\times10^{-6}$

Comment: This is correct, however for completeness and transparency it helps to explain how each result is formed.  (*e.g. pick the spades used for your hand, pick remaining cards for your hand, pick non-spades for partner's hand*).

Comment: I understood how you calculated number of favourable outcomes. But, in the total number of possible outcomes, can you please explain why you did $^{52}C_{13}\times ^{39}C_{13}$ instead of $^{52}C_{26}$?

Comment: @AnkitaPal the concept is strictly based on way bridge game is played. I and my parter must have 13 cards each. So for total number of outcomes we need to first find the number ways in which I can have 13 cards and for each of these possible way, we try to find out the number of ways in which my parter can have 13 cards out of the remaining 39 cards. Now as per your logic, if we find the number of ways in which 26 cards can be seleted from 52 cards, then we are not fixing the number of cards for myself and my parter. We can have a partition of 26 where I have 1 card and my parter has 25 cards.

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh Great explanation!!! Thank you very much.

Comment: @AnkitaPal you are welcome!